# Is the Starkiller Base's name a reference to early Star Wars development?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The name 'Starkiller' was used instead of 'Skywalker' in [early drafts](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Adventures_of_the_Starkiller,_Episode_I:_The_Star_Wars) of the first Star Wars movie. Is the name of the base in Episode VII an homage or reference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes

Abrams himself confirmed this at the *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* [panel at San Diego Comic-con 2015](https://youtu.be/8fMx670jOnw?t=36m50s)

**Transcript:**

> **Abrams:** The name of the base of the First Order is, in honour of the original last name of Luke Skywalker, is Starkiller Base.