# Is Director Krennic's name a reference?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Is Director Orson Krennic named after Orson Welles or Orson Scott Card?

I only ask because Star Wars has the funny quirk of sneaking in small references to outside universe things; THX-1138 being the most famous of them.  There are also references to other incarnations of itself, such as using Starkiller as [the name of the base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116722/31051) in the Force Awakens. They'll even sneak in people [working on the film](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gooti_Terez) as characters.  Both Orson Welles and Orson Scott Card have sci-fi influence, so that leads me to believe that they were being snuck in.

Comment: Knowing *Star Wars*, he’s [probably](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/123140/51379) [named after](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147330/51379) [someone working on the film](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gooti_Terez).

Comment: I'm willing to bet 500 rep that it wasn't Orson Scott Card (literally. if someone can prove me wrong via an answer, i'll award that answer 500 bounty).

Comment: @DVK I'm having a hard time proving *or* disproving either connection. I'd say there's very little. Most likely *not* OSC though.

Comment: @Mooz - 500 rep at stake! Work harder! :)

Comment: @DVK you Sound like my boss. If only they paid me in rep, then you and Richard would have no chance :p

Comment: Orson Welles was (briefly) considered for the voice of Darth Vader. Perhaps that's what they're referring to.

Comment: @Valorum That's literally the *only* piece of connection I've been able to dig up. Could just be a fanboy thing and we'll never know.

Comment: And I'd almost classify references to 'THX-1138' as an inside thing considering it is still Lucas, rather than referencing other creators. Quibble quibble :)

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida well, time to pay up! Jason Baker found an interview

Comment: @CBredlow - as Jason noted in the answer, it doesn't directly disprove that it wasn't Card as well. Still, worth a bounty just for the effort!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, Krennic was named for Orson Welles

*Rogue One* director Gareth Edwards answered this in a [2017 interview](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/the-secret-origin-of-jyn-ersos-name-revealed-by-rogue-one-mastermind-160705522.html)<sup>1</sup> with Yahoo Movies, where they ran several naming theories past him:

> **Kevin Polowy:** Director Orson Krennic; director Orson Welles.
>
> **Edwards:** The "Orson" bit, yes. The genius, yeah.

Unfortunately they didn't ask about Orson Scott Card, so it's unclear whether that was coincidence or not.

---

<sup>1</sup> Scroll to the bottom and watch the video, which I'm unable to embed or link to directly; the video's short, but this exchange begins at 0:38ish

Comment: Excellent find as always. You're turning out to be one of the sleuthiest of sleuths on this site!

Comment: @Mooz I credit my success to obsessively Twitter-stalkling Pablo Hidalgo; he [retweeted](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/819617106362699776) a link to a report on the interview

Comment: That SOB, I asked him directly about this, and I reply!  Lol.

Comment: ^ "no reply", not "I reply", damn auto-correct.